# Getter and setter for bounded wild card type property

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that contains a `List<? extends BaseType>`. Now `BaseType` can have two *subtypes*: `SubTypeA` and `SubTypeB`. At runtime the list may be either a `List<SubTypeA>` or `List<SubTypeB>`. How should the signature of *getter* and *setter* look  for this  property?

```
class ListHolder{

 private List<? extends BaseType> listOfBaseType;

 //getter and setter for listOfBaseType

}
```

Do we have to declare type parameter in the getter?

Comment: what is the purpose of your class? How are you using it?

Comment: Like any other accessor actually...

Comment: You could have let Eclipse generate the getter/setter for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, if you want to stick with the superclass just make it that way :

**Generic typing 1**

```
class ListHolder{

 private List<? extends BaseType> listOfBaseType;

 //getter and setter for listOfBaseType
 public List<? extends BaseType> getListOfBaseType(){...}
 public void setListOfBaseType(List<? extends BaseType>){...}

}
```

*Exemple 1*

```
ListHolder lh = new ListHolder();
lh.setListOfBaseType(new ArrayList<BaseTypeA>()); //OK
lh.setListOfBaseType(new ArrayList<BaseTypeB>()); //OK
List<BaseTypeB> l = lh.getListOfBaseType(); //KO too specific
List<? extends BaseType> l = lh.getListOfBaseType(); //OK
```

**Generic typing 2**

If you want strong control and safe conversion (although with this one you can't mix up types) :

```
class ListHolder<T extends BaseType>{

 private List<T> listOfBaseType;

 //getter and setter for listOfBaseType
 public List<T> getListOfBaseType(){...}
 public void setListOfBaseType(List<T>){...}

}
```

*Exemple 2*

```
ListHolder<BaseTypeA> lh = new ListHolder<BaseTypeA>();
lh.setListOfBaseType(new ArrayList<BaseTypeA>()); //OK
lh.setListOfBaseType(new ArrayList<BaseTypeB>()); //KO will not compile
List<BaseTypeB> l = lh.getListOfBaseType(); //KO will not compile
List<BaseTypeA> l = lh.getListOfBaseType(); //OK no need to cast
```

**Generic typing 3**

If you want more flexibility while keeping safety :

```
class ListHolder{

 private HashMap<Class<? extends BaseType>, List<? extends BaseType> hashListOfBaseType;

 //getter and setter for listOfBaseType
 public <T extends BaseType> List<T> getListOfBaseType(Class<T> clazz){
      return hashListOfBaseType.get(clazz);
 }

 public <T extends BaseType> void setListOfBaseType(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list){
      hashListOfBaseType.put(clazz, list);
 }

}
```

*Exemple 3*

```
ListHolder lh = new ListHolder();
lh.setListOfBaseType(BaseTypeA.class, new ArrayList<BaseTypeA>()); //OK
lh.setListOfBaseType(BaseTypeB.class, new ArrayList<BaseTypeB>()); //OK
List<BaseTypeA> l = lh.getListOfBaseType(BaseTypeA.class); //OK
List<BaseTypeB> l = lh.getListOfBaseType(BaseTypeB.class); //OK
```

Everything depends on what you need.... elaborate then I can be more specific

Comment: "although with this one you can't mix up types"--What do you mean by this? How can you mix types in the first case?

Comment: Mix up in the sense,are you talking about `subTypeA` and `subTypeB`?

Comment: @Geek I've explained a bit through examples, hope this clarify my point

Answer (score 3):

```
public List<? extends BaseType> getListOfBaseType() {
    return listOfBaseType;
}
public void setListOfBaseType(List<? extends BaseType> listOfBaseType) {
    this.listOfBaseType = listOfBaseType;
}
```

Comment: This causes a code smell `Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types ` - [RSPEC-1452](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452)